# NodeJS Addons (V8) and Threads

Tags: c++, node.js, multithreading, v8, node.js-addon

I want to be sure and understand if the threads can run properly inside of `v8 functions`. To understand this consider this example:
This server line:

```
var ob1 = addon.buffering(data,size,0,1,client.id);
```

Runs this v8 function:

```
void buffering(const FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    HandleScope scope(isolate);
    //(...input args....)
    t[iterator_test] = thread(&SREngineJulius::Audio_Buffering_thread, &Julius[client_id], node::Buffer::Data(bufferObj), size, final_read, inicio_read, client_id);
   //(....output results...)
}
```

And further:

```
var final result = addon.julius(client.id);
```

Will call:

```
void julius(const FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    HandleScope scope(isolate);
    //(..input args...)
    t[iterator_test].join();
    //(final routines)
    //(output results)
}
```

I can't test this code in extreme environment (with many many users), to see the performance. So when I call `buffering` and `buffering` creates a `thread`, the `v8 function` will wait for the execution of thread (to return, to the nodejs)? Or, **as I hope**, the waiting process will be done in `julius` with `join()`?

Comment: I would think that V8 will block only if your C++ code blocks.  If your main interface function in C++ does not block and returns immediately after starting the thread, then V8 should not block.  You will have to very carefully coordinate how you communicate back results asynchronously though.

Comment: Imagine that the thread takes 5seconds to give results. The server will be blocked in `buffering`? Or will be blocked in the `julius` in the remain time between buffering and julius (ex: between buffering and julius will pass 2secs so, the blocking time would be 3secs)? I expect the second option. @jfriend00

Comment: Does your `buffering()` function wait until the thread is done with it's work before returning or not?  If it waits, then it's blocking and V8 will block too.  If `buffering()` does not wait for the thread to be done, then V8 won't wait either, but I don't see how you communicate back results in that case.  Your Javascript interface does not look asynchronous (it has no callback) so if you're getting results back, then it must be blocking.

Comment: I am afraid it can't be. Because all of these funtions runs in events of [binaryjs](http://binaryjs.com/). The program Julius is fast to, so is possible to do that. I want immediate responses to a given event. But multithreading can be useful to run the program in all the cores of cpu. Right? @jfriend00

Comment: Then it will block V8.    V8 will be waiting for your addon function call to return.  It won't continue executing Javascript until that function returns.  An extra thread only helps use other cores if something is happening on the other cores.  Firing up a thread and then waiting for that thread to finish it's job doesn't really buy you anything that I can see.